# Losing usb port connectivity on USB-C hub

Tags: usb, 22.04

I recently bought a small (Linux compatible) hub offering HDMI, USB, Ethernet ports while connecting on my Dell XPS 13 laptop using USB-C. Typically on the USB ports I connect a wired Logitech Keyboard and mouse and sometimes some USB stick.

The problem I have is that intermittently the connectivity of the USB ports is lost and therefore I can't use the keyboard, mouse or anything else connected. The problem seems to affect only the USB ports as the HDMI, Ethernet remain unaffected. I can attempt to connect, disconnect things and eventually ports get recognised and working again but it's obviously a pain.

Has anyone else faced this or similar problem on Linux? and are there any suggestions that can fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tested it under other OS and concluded the problem is "on Linux"? At first glance I would say hardware, not software. Some interference or not enough power to the USB hub maybe because it has to keep constant power to the other devices in the same hub.

Comment: I agree with ChanganAuto - I had a similar issue due to interference or lack power - could not be fixed unfortunately - had to reorganize my USB-devices

- Do the devices work when plugged in directly?

Comment: I've seen the issue on Ubuntu 22.04 and Linux Mint 21. The USB devices always work when plugged directly.

Comment: You have your display and your Internet also connected to this hub? If it's not interference then you probably have too much connected to the same port. The USB port only has so much bandwidth. You're asking too much from a single port.

Comment: Yes HDMI and Ethernet, it's a good point, I've taken out the Ethernet cable now and will see if this makes things more stable.

Comment: Somewhere I saw that hubs have update-able firmware. Have you checked if yours can be updated?